# How to turn off Advanced Threat Protection and Security Center in Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azureportal, azure-security, advanced-threat-protection, azure-security-center

I have a project that I use for testing new things and I'm using the MSDN subscription, however most of it is used by ATP and Security Center.

[image: Budget cost breakdown]

Is there any way for me to turn this off? My subscription gets disabled every month since it goes over the spending limit.

Answer (score 3):

Defender for Cloud (formerly named Azure Security Center) can be enabled/disabled on the subscription level, which will take effect on all SQL databases or it can be enabled per SQL database. To enable / disable it, go to the relevant SQL database, navigate to Microsoft Defender for Cloud on the left pane and check the 'Enablement Status' then click 'Configure'
[image]

For more info refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/threat-detection-configure?view=azuresql

Comment: Thanks but this was already disabled.